# Angular6: "ERROR OK" default error logger

Tags: angular, spring-boot, download, angular-material

In my project, I'm using Angular6 with Springboot in the backend. And here what I'm trying to do is download generated docs file into a particular folder. But I'm getting an error message as follows,

> ERROR OK defaultErrorLogger    @   core.js:1633
>   push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError    @   core.js:1679
>   next    @   core.js:4255
>   schedulerFn

In `core.js` the chunk which throws an error is,

```
function defaultErrorLogger(console) {
    var values = [];
    for (var _i = 1; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
        values[_i - 1] = arguments[_i];
    }
    console.error.apply(console, __spread(values));
}
```

Actually I can't understand what's wrong with here and how to solve this. in my component, I'm using the following functions to generate and download the letter,

```
getGenaratedLetterTemplate(letter) {

  this.data.getGenaratedLetterTemplate(letter.letterId).subscribe(response => {
    this.getBasicDataFromBackend();
    saveAs(response,  letter.fullName + '_' + letter.letterTypeName + '.docx');
    console.log(response);
  });
}
generateletter(letterId) {
    console.log(letterId);

    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
    this.letterService.generateLetter(letterId).subscribe( result => {

      return result;
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

Finally, let me demo how the flow works now,
[image]

Comment: Are you sure your http call is completing fine?

Comment: Yes, because other functionalities are working fine. But I don't sure whether I have used the correct method to download a letter or not. If you briefly describe how to download some file which is generating it will so helpful to me to slove this

Comment: have you set response typa as 'arraybuffer'?

Comment: No where do I put that